# PHP socket script causes many and long CLOSE_WAIT socket connection

Tags: php, sockets

I have a PHP script (which I found online) that runs infinitely listening to a port and if there is a connection made to this port it will establish a `TCP connection`. However, when I ran this script and there are many connections (around 500), the number of `CLOSE_WAIT` connections increase. The remote device that is connected in this state is not able to connect again because the `CLOSE_WAIT` did not terminate.

```
// port info
$host = "0.0.0.0";
$port = 10260;
$pos = 1;

// don't timeout!
set_time_limit(0);
record("START");

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
$timeout = array('sec'=>3000,'usec'=>0);
$try = socket_set_option($sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVTIMEO,$timeout);

// Bind the socket to the address/port
if(!socket_bind($sock, $host, $port))
{
    echo socket_last_error() ;
    die('Could not bind to address');
}
record("SOCKET BIND OK");

// start listening for connections
$result = socket_listen($sock, 1024) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
record("SOCKET LISTEN OK");
$clients = array($sock);


// infinite while loop
while(1)
{

    // Setup clients listen socket for reading
    $read = $clients;

    $e = NULL;

    if (socket_select($read, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, 0,0) < 1) 
    {
       continue;
    }

    /* if a new read ready is being made add it to the client array */

    if (in_array($sock, $read)) {
        record("NEW CONNECTION");
        $clients[$pos] = $newsock = socket_accept($sock);
        $curpos = $pos;
        $pos++;
        socket_getpeername($newsock, $ip,$port);
        record("Incoming IP: {$ip} PORT: {$port}");
        // remove the listening socket from the clients-with-data array
        $key = array_search($sock, $read);
        unset($read[$key]);

    } // end if in_array

    // loop through all the clients that have data to read from
    foreach ($read as $read_key => $read_sock) {
        // read until newline or 1024 bytes
        // socket_read while show errors when the client is disconnected, so silence the error messages
        $key = $read_key;
        $fulldata = $data = @socket_read($read_sock, 1024);

        // check if the client is disconnected
        if ($data === false) {
            // remove client for $clients array
            $key = array_search($read_sock, $clients);
            socket_close($read_sock);
            unset($clients[$key]);

            record("NO DATA");

            // continue to the next client to read from, if any
            continue;
        }


        // .. do something with $data ...

    }


}

socket_close($sock);    
record("END");
die("DONE");
```

I tried to use `socket_close()` in the code but to no avail. `CLOSE_WAIT` seems to take longer to move to the next state.

Comment: I had a similar problem. In my case the problem was a single client that disconnecting abruptly and when its buffer was full, then nothing more could connecting to the port. Ever understood the problem, but I've fixed with a hand-made ping system with less tolerance (just an info that maybe could help you)

Comment: @chumkiu thanks for the info.  When you say the client's buffer was full, are you referring to the application or the remote device that connects to the port? If it is the application, is there a way to determine if the buffer is full or not? Thanks!

Comment: I means the `Recv-Q` for the ghost client in `netstat` on server. I don't found anything for read this in php (but my experience is by 6 years ago)

Comment: thanks @chumkiu - the problem I am having is caused by what mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: Even with improvements this script is going to have a limitation at 1024 sockets on Linux because even the newest PHP source still uses the select() call. HHVM at least uses poll().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found two problems in your code:

First, the 4th parameter(tv_sec) of socket_select should be NULL instead of 0. As described in the [Manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php), 0 causes high CPU load in a useless, endless loop, while NULL will block until anything happen:

> tv_sec may be zero , causing socket_select() to return immediately. This is useful for polling. If tv_sec is NULL (no timeout), socket_select() can block indefinitely.

The second, and I think this is the Reason for the CLOSE_WAIT is your test if $data is false. This only works on a gracefull closed connection, but as one comment [here](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php#89133) says, you also shold test on en empty string.
So change the one line to:

```
if (socket_select($read, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, NULL, 0) < 1)
```

and the other to:

```
// check if the client is disconnected
if ($data === false || $data === '') {
```

and you should be fine

Comment: thanks for pointing the errors. I have corrected them and it has helped alot. The `CLOSE_WAIT` states have moved to `LAST_ACK` when the connections are around 100-200. However, when it is reaching around 500, I am still getting a few `CLOSE_WAIT` connections (much less than before) with intermittent `LAST_ACK` state. Is this because it takes time for `socket_close` to complete?

Comment: Depending on what your script does with all the clients, it may take a while until socket_close is called an yes, in this time its still in CLOSE_WAIT state. As far as I remember, LAST_ACK means it waits for the client to send an ACK to the FIN packet. If one of this packets is eaten by a firewall or something, you have to wait until the kernel will clean the connection up by a timeout.